# Comparing rows from different tables in dataset C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I'm new to SQL and C# and I've been looking for answers for the issue I am having but couldn't find one that fully addresses it.

I have a C# application linked to a SQL Server database. In my database, I have 2 tables, one with customer information and another one with their account information. This second table can have more than 1 row per customer or even no rows for a specific customer if they don't have an account.

Here are the two tables:

Customer table:

[image: Customer table]

Account Information table:

[image: Account Information table]

Expected output would be:

```
Franklin, Ben ($32) 
Jones, Thomas ($5) 
Tesla, Tesla
```

I'm trying to write a method that loads all customers to a list as well as their account information but I am getting wrong account information for each customer (i.e. Chequing and Saving). This happens when the customer either doesn't have an account or the rows I'm comparing have different customer numbers. All names are on my list but with wrong account info. Is there an easier way to do this? Or what am I doing wrong? I really appreciate any help on this.

Here's the code:

```
public List<CustomerAccountManager> LoadAllCustomers()
{
    SqlCommand cmd1, cmd2;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda;

    DataSet sqlds = new DataSet();

    decimal? Chequing = null;
    decimal? Saving = null;
    int CustomerNumber = 0;

    string FirstName = string.Empty;
    string LastName = string.Empty;

    List<CustomerAccountManager> AllCustomers = new List<CustomerAccountManager>();

    cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Customer.CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName FROM Customer", Connection);
    cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Account.CustomerNumber, AccountType, Balance FROM Account WHERE AccountType = 'C' OR AccountType = 'S' ", Connection);
    sqlds.Tables.Add("Customers");
    sqlds.Tables.Add("Acct");

    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    sqlda.Fill(sqlds.Tables["Customers"]);

    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    sqlda.Fill(sqlds.Tables["Acct"]);

    foreach (DataRow cust in sqlds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow acct in sqlds.Tables[1].Rows)
        {
            CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cust["CustomerNumber"]);
            int CustomerNumberAcct = Convert.ToInt32(acct["CustomerNumber"]);

            if (CustomerNumber == CustomerNumberAcct)
            {
                CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cust["CustomerNumber"]);
                FirstName = Convert.ToString(cust["FirstName"]);
                LastName = Convert.ToString(cust["LastName"]);
                string AcctType = Convert.ToString(acct["AccountType"]);

                if (AcctType == "C")
                    Chequing = Convert.ToDecimal(acct["Balance"]);

                if (AcctType == "S")
                    Saving = Convert.ToDecimal(acct["Balance"]);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < sqlds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; index++)
                {
                    DataRow search = sqlds.Tables[0].Rows[index];
                    int customernosearch = Convert.ToInt32(search["CustomerNumber"]);

                    if (customernosearch == CustomerNumberAcct)
                    {
                        CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(acct["CustomerNumber"]);
                        FirstName = Convert.ToString(cust["FirstName"]);
                        LastName = Convert.ToString(cust["LastName"]);
                        string AcctType = Convert.ToString(acct["AccountType"]);

                        if (AcctType == "C")
                            Chequing = Convert.ToDecimal(acct["Balance"]);
                        else
                            Chequing = null;

                        if (AcctType == "S")
                            Saving = Convert.ToDecimal(acct["Balance"]);
                        else
                            Saving = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        AllCustomers.Add(new CustomerAccountManager(CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName, Chequing, Saving));
    }

    return (AllCustomers);
}
```

Comment: This might be easy to do within a query in stead of in c# code. Why dont you provide some sample data and expected outcome than we can help with that query

Comment: Sure, thank you so much! Here are the two tables:
CustomerNumber FirstName LastName
100000                  Ben                 Franklin
100001                 Thomas          Jones
100002                 Tesla           Tesla

CustomerNumber AccountType Balance
100000                 C                 26
100000                 S                 6
100001                 C                 5
I would expect my list to look like this:
Franklin, Ben($32.00)
Jones, Thomas($5.00)
Tesla,Tesla

Comment: dont put the data in a comment. Edit your question and put it there, this is to hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best way to do things, but I will stick to your code. Simply delete the `else` part, it's messing everything. The first `if (CustomerNumber == CustomerNumberAcct)` part is doing the job.

Tip: You don't need to manually create the tables in the `DataSet`, the `Fill()` function will create them automatically.

```
public List<CustomerAccountManager> LoadAllCustomers() {
    SqlCommand cmd1, cmd2;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda;
    DataSet sqlds = new DataSet();

    decimal? Chequing = null;
    decimal? Saving = null;
    int CustomerNumber = 0;
    string FirstName = string.Empty;
    string LastName = string.Empty;

    List<CustomerAccountManager> AllCustomers = new List<CustomerAccountManager>();

    cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Customer.CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName FROM Customer", Connection);
    cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Account.CustomerNumber, AccountType, Balance FROM Account WHERE AccountType = 'C' OR AccountType = 'S' ", Connection);
    //sqlds.Tables.Add("Customers");
    //sqlds.Tables.Add("Acct");
    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    sqlda.Fill(sqlds.Tables["Customers"]);
    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    sqlda.Fill(sqlds.Tables["Acct"]);

    foreach (DataRow cust in sqlds.Tables[0].Rows) {
        foreach (DataRow acct in sqlds.Tables[1].Rows) {
            CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cust["CustomerNumber"]);
            int CustomerNumberAcct = Convert.ToInt32(acct["CustomerNumber"]);
            if (CustomerNumber == CustomerNumberAcct) {
                CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cust["CustomerNumber"]);
                FirstName = Convert.ToString(cust["FirstName"]);
                LastName = Convert.ToString(cust["LastName"]);
                string AcctType = Convert.ToString(acct["AccountType"]);
                if (AcctType == "C")
                    Chequing = Convert.ToDecimal(acct["Balance"]);
                if (AcctType == "S")
                    Saving = Convert.ToDecimal(acct["Balance"]);
            }
        }
        AllCustomers.Add(new CustomerAccountManager(CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName, Chequing, Saving));
     }
    return (AllCustomers);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use LINQ to achieve all that in one line.

**EDIT** If you want to keep doing it the same way, I suggest merging both your SQL queries in one which makes your life much easier. Like this:

```
public List<CustomerAccountManager> LoadAllCustomers() {
    string sql;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda;
    DataSet sqlds = new DataSet();

    decimal? Chequing = null;
    decimal? Saving = null;
    int CustomerNumber = 0;
    string FirstName = string.Empty;
    string LastName = string.Empty;

    List<CustomerAccountManager> AllCustomers = new List<CustomerAccountManager>();
    sql = @"SELECT c.CustomerNumber, c.FirstName, c.LastName,
                   ca.Balance AS Chequing, sa.Balance AS Saving
            FROM Customer c
            LEFT JOIN Account ca ON ca.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
                                 AND ca.AccountType = 'C'
            LEFT JOIN Account sa ON sa.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
                                 AND sa.AccountType = 'S'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);
    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sqlda.Fill(sqlds);

    foreach (DataRow cust in sqlds.Tables[0].Rows) {
       CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cust["CustomerNumber"]);
       FirstName = Convert.ToString(cust["FirstName"]);
       LastName = Convert.ToString(cust["LastName"]);
       Chequing = Convert.ToDecimal(cust["Chequing"]);
       Saving = Convert.ToDecimal(cust["Saving"]);
       AllCustomers.Add(new CustomerAccountManager
                            (CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName, Chequing, Saving));
     }
    return (AllCustomers);
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I tried your code, but one name is missing and a duplicate is showing instead. The reason why I had the else is because I also need to display customers on the customer table that are not in the account table :/

Comment: I see, why don't you use LINQ instead of coding it by yourself?

Comment: I'm new to SQL and don't know how to use it :(

Comment: Thank you! I am trying your code but I'm getting the same total for the second and third customer. I have edited my question with all the info :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. The `as` is a reserved word in SQL. I don't know why you didn't get an error. I've updated my answer, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct than your query would look something like this than

```
declare @customer table (number int, firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50))
declare @account table (number int, acctype varchar(50), balance decimal(16,2))

insert into @customer (number, firstname, lastname)
values (100000, 'Ben', 'Franklin'), (100001, 'Thomas', 'Jones'), (100002, 'Tesla', 'Tesla')

insert into @account (number, acctype, balance)
values (100000, 'C', 26), (100000, 'S', 6), (100001, 'C', 5)

SELECT c.Number, c.FirstName, c.LastName,
       ac.Balance AS CheckBalans,
       ac2.Balance AS SavingBalans,
       isnull(ac.Balance, 0) + isnull(ac2.Balance, 0) as total 
FROM @customer c
  LEFT JOIN @account ac ON ac.Number = c.Number
                       AND ac.AccType = 'C'
  LEFT JOIN @account ac2 ON ac2.Number = c.Number
                         AND ac2.AccType = 'S'
```

The outcome is this

```
Number  FirstName   LastName    CheckBalans SavingBalans    total   
------  ---------   --------    ----------- ------------    -----   
100000  Ben         Franklin    26          6               32  
100001  Thomas      Jones       5           null            5   
100002  Tesla       Tesla       null        null            0
```

Keep in mind though that when there are more account types this query will not work anymore

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure, I would insert this piece of code into my SqlCommand? And delete the other one, right?

Comment: Yes. But with this query (or the query of Racil's answer) you only need one query and one command anymore, and all youre comparing in code can be deleted also. The query does it all